# What toys are the four realms supposed to represent?

Tags: the-nutcracker-and-the-four-realms

In the 2018 Disney movie "The Nutcracker and the Four Realms",

> the people there were originally toys, brought to life by Clara's mother, Marie. We saw that tin soldiers were literally tin soldiers, the mice being wind-up toy mice, the nutcracker obviously a nutcracker, and Sugar Plum a Barbie-ish doll.

What were the original forms of other beings in the movie, such as those from the Land of Flowers, Land of Snowflakes, and Land of *(whisper)* Amusement?